# "Frame Rectangle" vs. "Layout Rectangle" in Xcode

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xib

What's the difference of the two?
I haven't found any difference in my projects when using either one, but it's bothering me that I don't know what either is for.

Please advise!

[image]
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914102/whats-the-difference-between-frame-and-layout-in-interface-builders-size-inspe

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The layout rectangle is the apparent visual size of the control. It is different from the actual frame, since there might be drop shadows or inset effects that are outside of the visually distinct portion of the control.

[What's the difference between frame and layout in Interface builder's size inspector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914102/whats-the-difference-between-frame-and-layout-in-interface-builders-size-inspe)

Comment: ...Just for clarification, layout is just the item, and frame is everything including shadow?